# How to reuse a term in calc macro of latexcalc?

Tags: calculations

Although [latexcalc](http://latexcalc.sourceforge.net/) seems to be no longer in active development, I'd like to know whether it is possible to reuse a term which I want to both display and calculate, but only maintain once, e.g

```
\def\myterm{1+2+4 \cdot{\frac{1}{2}}}
$\myterm = \calc{\myterm}$
```

which I'd expect to result in

```
1+2+4*1/2 = 5
```

Both `\calc` and `\varcalc` fail with `error   (line xy): empty or invalid equation block` if a user defined macro is placed in the argument. The same if the term is defined with `\newcommand`, e.g. `\newcommand{\myterm}{...}`.

I understand the problem that `latexcalc` is an external program invoked explicitly on the command line and obviously doesn't parse the document for macro definitions and replace them before calculating in a second run. I just want to make sure I didn't miss anything regarding a workaround.

Using `sagetex` is not acceptable because it can't deal with LaTeX markup, e.g. `\frac` which reduces reusability dramatically.

I'm using latexcalc 1.0.1 on Ubuntu 14.10.

Compilable example (with `latexcalc --pdflatex /path/to/file.tex`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\myterm{1+2+4 \cdot \frac{1}{2}}
$\myterm = \calc{\myterm}$
\end{document}
```

`\varcalc` doesn't work neither:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\myterm{1+2+4 \cdot \frac{1}{2}}
$\varcalc{x}{\myterm} \solver{x} \myterm = \answer$
\end{document}
```

(fails with

```
error   (line 4): empty or invalid equation block
error   (line 4): undefined variable x`
```

) as does a comination of `\solver` and `\answer`, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\myterm{1+2+4 \cdot \frac{1}{2}}
$ \solver{\myterm} \myterm = \answer$
\end{document}
```

(fails with `error   (line 4): empty or invalid equation block`).

Comment: Please complete your code to provide a small, compilable document illustrating your question aka Minimal (non-)Working Example. This makes it a lot easier for people to help (and so increases the chances they will!). Also, what is `latexcalc`? Or where is it?

Comment: Can't you use `\solver` and `\answer` etc.? That is, I take it that `latexcalc` is parsing for very specific things: it is not parsing the TeX code in its entirety. I take it that those things are supposed to signal the bits it needs to pay attention to and it is going to ignore everything else.

Comment: @cfr Do you means the same thing I mentioned in my question. If not, I don't get it, please explain. I added the results for `\varcalc` and `\solver`. I don't see other options left.

Comment: No, I think you can't use a TeX macro e.g. `\term`. You need to use e.g. `\solver` and `\answer` ***instead***.

Comment: @cfr That's what I did, but I added another example as seems to have been unclear in the first place. I appreciate your attempt to help, but it's more of a support for trial and error which I can conduct myself. I'd very much appreciate a verification of falsification of your thought that using macros is possible posted as a tested answer.

Comment: I said I didn't think it was possible - not that it was. But, anyway, I'll leave this question since I don't have `latexcalc` and so cannot test.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this but it is hard to tell, just from the information given, whether it would serve your purpose or not.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\newcommand*\calc[1]{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1}\pgfmathresult}
\begin{document}
\def\myterm{1+2+4}
$\myterm = \calc{\myterm}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is limited to LaTeX-free input. E.g. `\def\myterm{1+2+4 \cdot \frac{1}{2}}` doesn't work. The implications are the same like for `sagetex` described in the question, which is dramatic decrease of reusability of markup.

Comment: @KarlRichter Since I have never heard of `latexcalc`, CTAN knows nothing about it and you have provided essentially no information (e.g. a link), it isn't surprising that it fails to do whatever-it-is-that-you-want-but-haven't-said.